# Viewing specific log file in Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

I'm trying to view a specific log in my Heroku app. I know I can view my app's Heoku log by running the command `heroku log --app my-app-name` but I want to specify the log file, as there are multiple in my app. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Heroku Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging), the logs are aggregated to a single stream. This can make sorting through them with the CLI utility difficult.

You can always use `grep` to filter the CLI log in real-time, but this is ineffective if you want historical logs.

```
heroku log -t --app my-app-name | grep INFO
```

Check out the [Papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail) addon for easier historical filtering.

Comment: Thanks both of these tips are super helpful. I'm reading about log drains now.